# Pluralization issue in the Profile page - badge count

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, plurals

There is a pluralization issue on the [Profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=profile).
Due to the recent badge section changes on the Profile page, for the single badge count, it is showing as "badges" but it is supposed to be "badge".

Screenshot for reference: (emphasis mine)

[image: Badges]

Comment: Only if you read it as "1 gold badges" rather than "gold badges: 1"

Comment: I guess you haven't heard that pluralization discrepancies on the Stack Exchange network is a feature, not a bug :)

Comment: Obligatory comment about something depreciated being done with something depreciated

Comment: Obligatory comment about [*depreciation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depreciation) not being the same thing as [*deprecation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation).

Comment: It would be simple to solve if we had a "badge" badge. So, you get a silver badge the first time you earn another silver badge. The issue of whether or not to pluralize the number zero has been deftly avoided by using the caption, *"This user doesn't have any silver badges yet."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The pluralization issue has been fixed.

Screenshot for reference: (emphasis mine)[image: ref]

Comment: What emphasis?  - Do you mean the freehand circles?

Comment: @41686d6564 I crop the "1 badge" screenshot from three different (for gold/silver/bronze) users. I'm not able to find a user with only one gold, silver, bronze badge.